# How to set array of object inside async storage in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am trying to set array of object inside async storage but I did not set it . Could someone please help me how to achieve this . Thanks

**Code**

```
  let joined = this.state.product.concat(product);
    this.props.setNotification(joined);
    AsyncStorage.setItem("count", joined);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to stringify the array and store it

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('count', JSON.stringify(joined));
```

You will have to parse the string when you retrieve it

```
const storedArray = await  AsyncStorage.getItem('count');
const array = JSON.parse(storedArray)
```